# Getting following error while trying to train image classifier for color images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am getting the following error:

```
 ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 12390 input samples and 4130 target samples.
```

The error occurs for following line of code

```
history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=110, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: As error suggests the length of X and y should be same.

Comment: how to do that? I have tried reshaping also, but getting the error there also

Comment: How you create `X` and `y` ? Add that code snippet in your question

Comment: It got solved. I had to run a loop 3 times when I was appending X label. It caused y label to get appended 3 times when X label was being appended. Thanks for the help